# Turning an object into a string

Tags: javascript, html

like the title suggests i want to turn an object into a string, the reasons are the following:
i want to create an alert message saying that your browser is currently using another language as default. ive been learning code for a month and a half now, so i know this isnt the most optimal way to do this:
here is the code:

```
            <body>
            <div class="container">
           <script>

           var lang= navigator.language;


           if (""+ lang == es-US) {
            alert ("Your browser is in spanish, change it");


         }

        </script>
```

Comment: You don't need the `"" +`, as a side note.  `navigator.language` is already a string

Answer (score 1):

Just put quotes around es-US:

```
<script>    
var lang = navigator.language;    
if ("" + lang == "es-US") {
alert ("Your browser is in spanish, change it");    
}    
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Whoops, I didn't realize the `if (""+ lang == es-US)` didn't had the `""` signs in es-US.

Comment: Rather than posting an answer saying you made a typo in your question, update your original question (Edit link in the bottom left of it), and delete this non-answer.